# Correct way to include a header file that is different for precompiled binaries vs manually compiled binaries

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, include, debian

So I have a program that uses [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/), and I use cmake to make it.

The problem is that I want it to compile smoothly for 2 different situations:

1. For a Linux system, say Debian, one could install a pre-compiled `libopenblas` with `apt-get install libopenblas`, which works fine with my program. This is because I have the include:

   ```
   #include <openblas/cblas.h>
   ```

Now this option is good for tests and not for the real deal. The performance of my program will be better if used with a user-compiled version of OpenBLAS, because OpenBLAS compiles differently for every computer (processor dependent). But this pre-compiled version is good if you wanna play around with the program.

2. For a version that anyone compiles by themselves, the structure of an OpenBLAS installation is:

   ```
   ├── bin
   ├── include
   │   ├── cblas.h
   │   ├── f77blas.h
   │   ├── lapacke_config.h
   │   ├── lapacke.h
   │   ├── lapacke_mangling.h
   │   ├── lapacke_utils.h
   │   └── openblas_config.h
   └── lib
       ├── libopenblas.a -> libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.19.a
       ├── libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.19.a
       ├── libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.19.so
       ├── libopenblas.so -> libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.19.so
       └── libopenblas.so.0 -> libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.19.so
   ```

As you see here, there's no directory called "openblas", which means my include should be:

```
#include <cblas.h>
```

but then this is dangerous, because the file `cblas.h` is not only for OpenBLAS, and may be available from other implementations of BLAS. This leads to the file being available, but the function I need from it `openblas_set_num_threads(int num_threads);` not being available. So if I, by default, add the directory `openblas` to my cmake's include list, the wrong file may be included if the user doesn't have a custom installation of OpenBLAS.

**So my question is:** How would you deal with this correctly, such that *if* a pre-compiled version of OpenBLAS is not present, then do the correct include without the `openblas` directory?

Let me know if you require more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution I found is to make a DEFINE in cmake if a local, compiled library is found

```
if(${foundOpenBLAS})
    message("I found OpenBLAS that you compiled.")
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mylibs -L"${OpenBLASPath}/lib")
else()
    message("I couldn't find OpenBLAS that you compiled, so I'm assuming that you have it installed in your system.")
    add_definitions(-DOPENBLAS_FROM_SYSTEM)
endif()
```

Now in the C++ code, we do this:

```
#ifdef OPENBLAS_FROM_SYSTEM
#include <openblas/cblas.h>
#else
#include "include/cblas.h"
#endif
```

The first version is when OpenBLAS isn't found, and it's the default Debian include. The other case, is if OpenBLAS is found. This will include the right file.